# Ionic CLI start : starterkit v3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, ionic-cli

with the command ionic start myapp tabs. We retrieve the starterkit from version 2. But I want to start an application Ionic v3. Ionic CLI is not up to date? All like other commands: ionic generate ??

Comment: Can you show the details of `ionic info`?

Comment: cli packages:
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

System:
    Node : v6.11.0
    npm  : 3.10.10
    OS   : Windows 7

Comment: with ionic start : git  >> 
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/
-----
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-tabs/
-----
V2 not V3

Comment: Can you show the `package.json` file?

Comment: '
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
'

It seems good, be angular 4 for ionic3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This CLI is working perfectly fine.

```
ionic start myapp tabs
```

You can see that on your `package.json` file as shown below.On there `"ionic-angular": "3.6.0",` means `Ionic 3` app with `Angular 4+`.No issues.

```
{
  "name": "MediaApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update in to ionic version 3 in command lind type

```
npm update -g ionic
```

then it will be updated to the latest ionic version,which is ionic 3 
Then go to the source code file which you have your code, by pressing shift key in windows right click then you can go to command prompt in there if you using git bash command line you can get that by only ricght clicking.in command line type

```
ionic serve
```

and hit enter.
This thing worked for me